# elmah error handling - store in database

Tags: elmah

How do I get ELMAH to store the cached errors in my database?

Has anyone implemented it already? If yes please guide me how to do that step by steps please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an article that describes how to configure ELMAH to log to a SQL Server database.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ThirdParty/ErrorloggingUsingElmah.aspx